# Google font "Source Sans Pro" does not look smooth on Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts

Why does the font on the left side within the list look so *chopy* on Chrome? The used and rendered font-face is `Source Sans Pro` with a `font-size: 16px` and `line-heigth: 24px`.

I have double checked the zoom on chrome which is on 100%. When I zoom into the page, the font gets smoother. Also the text within the badges somehow looks strange.

What can I do, to make this font look smoother?

[image]

---

**Update**

After some trial and error I found the culprit, though I don't understand why it's causing the issues.

I have integrated the font using an `@import` statement like the following within my scss:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro|Source+Sans+Pro:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i&display=swap');
```

When replacing the import url with this...

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');
```

... or when downloading the font and using it with a `@font-face` statement the fonts went smooth again...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Why is that? Also now the bootstrap classes `font-weight-normal` (400), `font-weight-light` (300) and `font-weight-ligther` (lighter?) all look the same.

P.S. This seems to be related: [Google Webfonts and Anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081545/google-webfonts-and-anti-aliasing)

Comment: Can you reproduce an example here?

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal, reproducible code. Also, perhaps a link so we may be able to debug.

Comment: Could be either a CSS property to change/add (such as `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`), or an OS-wide configuration to adjust (ClearType on Windows). Could we get more info, perhaps an example?

Comment: Sorry for that. Will update my question in a second.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce it and apply all styles that chrome's developer tool's comes up with (besides the `user agent stylesheets`). However the reproduced example always looks smooth/antialiased in contrast to my code which I send a screenshot. I have also tried to disable (via chrome dev tools) all styles applied to this element with out luck. What I can do to further tackle this issue? I have also tried adding `* { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }` which didn't change a thing.

Comment: If you can't show the code that produces this, then there's not much we can do.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Thing is, everything is bundled using webpack. I'll have to put it apart step by step first... will get back to this thread

Comment: Please see my updated question. It seems as if the way I am importing the fonts is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts on Windows always look less attractive than they do on macOs. That being said, there are 2 things i always have in my typography css to ensure I have maximum control over how it is rendered.

```
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

edit: Feel free to play around with values, you will get different results so find the one you prefer, this is my personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for replying and the tip. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried using this with your initial import ? Or did you test the updated version where you don't specify font weights you want to import? Try it with both and let me know if you see improvements.